# connect gy512 is not visible by i2c bus

Tags: accelerometer, mpu6050, gyroscope

I am a newbie. Please help to make gy512 visible on i2c interface.

i did

sda - a4
scl - a5
vcc - 5v
gnd - gnd

I have used i2c sticker scatch and use PC monitor.

Comment: What is a GY512? I could only find the GY521, which seems to be a breakout board for the MPU6050. And I guess you have used the standard I2C scanner sketch. Have you tried adding pullup resistors to the I2C lines (like 4.7kOhm)?

Comment: This question is hard to solve with so much info missing. Could you please add more info and perhaps some pictures.